# Android : how to use ViewPager to swipe each item of my ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a **listview** in my **mainActivity** and I have a **detailActivity** to display listview items.

I want to swipe those **items** using **ViewPager** inside my detailActivity.

mylistview is populated using a json feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many tutorials and examples on the web. Just have a look at [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging) page for example.

If you are using Android Studio you can press right button on the package and create new Activity from template. Pick *Tabbed Activity*, it will contain layout with ViewPager and basic implementation.

Comment: Oo , I should have started from there ! I see more clear now in this viewpager concept. Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1):

To implement the detailActivity , you need to supply a PageAdapter to the view pager.

Extend the FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter depending on the need and set it to the ViewPager.

Pass the same json feed as to the listview in the main activity to the above adapter and implement it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you,  [link]http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging[/link] helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open new tabs when each ListView item is clicked?
If so then you should in your onItemClick() method for the list view set the viewPager to the position of the desired fragment:

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(positionOfDesiredFragment);
```

Otherwise could you please explain your goal in more detail.